# Preserve In-App Facebook Access Token for Safari

Tags: ios, facebook, safari

I'm making an app that is running on iOS 6.1.3 and Facebook SDK 3.5. When the app launches, the user is asked to authenticate with Facebook. I ask for read permissions here and have an access token after a successful connection.

However, one of my features involves showing a UIWebView popup inside of my app that is on the Facebook mobile website. Ideally, I'd like to be able to have the user load this UIWebView and be logged into Facebook automatically on the mobile web version without having to reenter their credentials. Is this possible? If so, how could I go about doing this?

I guess a simpler way of describing what I'm trying to do is:

1) User logs into MyApp and grants me permissions with an access token.
2) User opens Safari. Right now, going to m.facebook.com will prompt user to login once more.
Q) How can I get it to where the user is automatically logged in on m.facebook.com using the access token that I have?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to persist the token after the initial login or how to log the user in with the token later? Use NSUserDefaults to persist the token.

Comment: @JeffCompton Thanks for your quick reply. Sorry that this is kinda hard for me to explain. The user logs in via Facebook in my app. At some point, I need to redirect them to the Facebook mobile website in Safari to do something that the Facebook API doesn't allow me to do in-app. However, right now, once the user gets to Safari, they are prompted to sign in. I'm wondering if there's a way I can skip the login when they get to Safari since they have already signed in while using my app. Thanks Jeff!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the facebook api.  It looks like you can authenticate a user using a token and javascript, but I'm still trying to find out if you can do it using objective c.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/

Comment: @JeffCompton thanks for helping out. I'm experimenting with my options. For example, I feel like if I use the Safari quick-switch method to authenticate the user when the app first launches, then maybe Safari will preserve the access token as well.

Comment: It seems like the app token can't be used to log the user into facebook's site, because the app token has specific privileges tied to it and facebook's site grants more access than is allowed.  I feel like you're on the right route by trying to cache the user's credentials for your app and Safari (UIWebView?) at the same time.

Comment: @JeffCompton I'm gonna try it out tonight and I'll post back if I can get it to work. I appreciate your help though! :)